# Magento2.1.0 showing error Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed while saving product in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, products-management, magento2.1.0

I am facing this error **Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed** when i try to save the product in admin. I checked the theme configuration it was assigned to the stores. Recently i have upgraded from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0.Also i have checked the theme directory **registration.php** file exists. Anyone came across this issue.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Finally I fixed it by commenting out the exception under `vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Simple.php`.

```
if (in_array($placeholder, $this->optionalParams)) {
    return [];
} else {
    return [];
    //throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Required parameter '{$placeholder}' was not passed");
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the error, only doesn't show it anymore. (I think Vu Anh's solution is more a fix)

Comment: This is not the right way of fixing this issue! Check the answer from Vu Anh.

Comment: This is not a best solution. Please don't do this

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue, it's just hiding the error. Need to know the root cause of the issue.

Comment: i feel like you are trying to make fun of error. Ok. HAHAHA there you go.

Answer (score 45):

This error appears when you remove a template folder, which is still referenced in the database. The simplest way to fix it is, go to the database, and in table 'theme', find the theme name which does not exist in `app/design/frontend/package`.

`DELETE` the reference to the missing theme from the table.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: PERFECT.. WORKED LIKE A CHARM

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: 2 records was extra in my database I deteleted BUt still not working

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm that the answer by [Vu Anh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135402/243) works. Here's an explanation **why this happens when products are saved**, although the deleted theme is used nowhere:

After saving a product, the **image cache** is regenerated for all themes. Each theme can have its own image size formats, defined in `etc/view.xml` and all of these will be generated.

But instead of looking for the configured themes in all stores, Magento goes through all themes in the `theme` table.

If you did not properly uninstall a theme and just removed the files, the orphaned entry refers to a nonexistent path and the described exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error **Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed**. I work with 2.1.0 from the beginning, not with updating. And I have one custom product attribute "style".

The problem occurs when I try to save the new photo in the material. Without the image, the product saved normally.

Fix with commenting the exception under the file:

```
vendor/magento/framework/view/design/Fallbck/Rule/Simple.php
```

It worked for me. But I think it's a hack.

Comment: This is definitely a hack. Fix the problem instead of removing the exception.